# Iptables LOG rules -- what are they good for?

Tags: iptables, log-files

The arch wiki reads,

> The LOG target can be used to log packets that hit a rule. Unlike other targets like ACCEPT or DROP, the packet will continue moving through the chain after hitting a LOG target.

So, you could set up a rule that would log all traffic for some service, such as SSH.  Right?

What would that be good for?  Are there programs for crunching/analyzing such log files?  Are they human-readable?

Answer (score 3):

1. You could, but as you imply, logging all packets isn't a terribly useful function. We have things like `tcpdump` for that and they don't have to be always turned on.
2. `LOG` is primarily useful immediately prior to a rejection or a drop, particularly at the end of *drop/reject by default* policies. This allows you to debug the traffic that you're discarding. The more complicated your policy is, the more value you get out of this.
3. Yes.
4. Yes.

If you don't want the messages going to syslog, `ULOG` and `NFLOG` targets are also available, but they require separate logging programs to handle the messages.